# Steam crashing on launch, 16.04

Tags: steam

2 days ago I left for vacation, I get back ready to play some *Counter Strike: Global offensive* on steam, but when I launch steam it does nothing, I try to type a line in steam to launch steam, but it says this

```
:/usr/bin/steam: line 194: /home/sean/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Success
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
Also, if you know please give a step to step tutorial on how to fix this cause im new to Ubuntu. Thanks!